# Abstract submission with COD

Tags: webforms, distributions

I would like to be able to let people submit abstracts with the Conference Organising Distribution. Is there a way already implemented? I did not see this.

The idea would be that people can enter information about themselves, the abstract and upload the tex file and select the session/track that they want to present in.

AND that we can approve the abstracts and add them to the schedule.

Is there an easy way for this? Seems like a pretty (academic) conference requirement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question was [cross-posted on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2209541) and it got an answer there.
it basically explains that *session submission* is meant for this.